# SQL script for ibm i am getting error "**" expected after this token i can't figure out

Tags: sql

The below shows sql scripts for ibm. I'm new to `IBMi` cannot figure what they want.

```
  Formatting error encountered...   Line 85: "**" expected after this token   Failed to format 1 statements
```

```
/*  Produce outfile first via this command on IBMi:*/;
CL: DSPOBJD OBJ(SCRUBLIB/*ALL) OBJTYPE(*ALL) DETAIL(*BASIC) OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) OUTFILE(HERAPERM/SCRUBLIB);


/* Build objects in SCRUBLIB not in Activity from Journal Dump summary file */;
```

```sql
--drop table HERAPERM.SCRUBLITST;
    CREATE TABLE HERAPERM.SCRUBLITST AS
            (
/* Build Activity from Journal Dump summary file */
                WITH scrub_activity AS (
                         SELECT joobj,
                                jouser,
                                entry_count,
                                first_entry,
                                last_entry,
                                CASE
                                    WHEN
                                        jocode = 'J' -- start / end journalling.
                                        OR jouser IN ('JGP212', 'KXK632', 'DJY881', 'S_DBAADMIN', 
      'SYSADMIN', 'S_PRDSUPT')
                                        THEN 'admin'
                                    WHEN jouser IN ('QUICK', 'QSYS')
                                        AND -- ignore replication & other background activity
                                        ((jocode = 'F'
                                                AND joentt IN ('CB', 'CL', 'OP'))
                                                -- OP = open, CL = closed, CB = member changed (generally 
     for stats info)
                                            OR (jocode = 'D'
                                                AND joentt IN ('DH', 'DW')) -- save activitiy
                                            ) THEN 'system'
                                    WHEN
                                        jouser IN ('MISRBTAZ',
                                            'MISRBTEA', 'MISRBTCZ', 'MISRBT', 'MISRBTNW', 'MISRBTCT', 
       'MISRBTLR', 'MISRBTPA',
                                            'MISRBTUS', 'MISRBTCW', 'MISRBTLF', 'MISRBTCA', 'MISRBTMS', 
      'MISRBTFT')
                                        THEN 'production jobs'
                                    WHEN
                                        jouser IN ('TURNOVER',
                                            'PGMRADMIN', 'MXE325', 'MXE325', 'ELP847', 'KVP548', 
    'WMC577', 'CKK315', 'TDM450',
                                            'AAG907', 'RAV995', 'AGG582', 'GDD759', 'CDJ667', 'MBB128', 
    'JHH085', 'AAA249',
                                            'AGC549', 'JID202', 'V_KNN648', 'FSS256', 'DHT776', 'XPP203', 
    'RNF185', 'KRR842',
                                            'KOT500', 'RKK970', 'KNN152', 'SRR886', 'PPP228', 'V_GVV273', 
    'JFF869', 'KSS648',
                                            'KKK588', 'JFF449', 'JAC000', 'DWW693', 'SSS865', 'RPK746', 
    'V_FSS633', 'SAA508')
                                        THEN 'developer activity'
                                    ELSE 'other'
                                END AS activity_type
                             FROM techcmds.scrubjrn1
                             WHERE joobj <> '' -- only interested in object changes, not receiver 
    switches, etc.
                                    AND SUBSTR(last_entry, 1, 2) = to_char(current_date - 2 MONTH, 'MM')
                                   -- Only objects activity (2 months ago)
                                   OR joobj <> '' -- only interested in object changes, not receiver 
    switches, etc.
                                   AND SUBSTR(last_entry, 1, 2) = to_char(current_date - 1 MONTH, 'MM')
                                   -- Only objects activity (1 month ago)
                                   OR joobj <> '' -- only interested in object changes, not receiver 
    switches, etc.
                                   AND SUBSTR(last_entry, 1, 2) = to_char(current_date, 'MM')
                                   -- Only objects activity (Current month)
                     ),
                     scrub_activity_sum AS (
                         SELECT joobj,
                                activity_type,
                                SUM(entry_count) entry_count,
                                MIN(first_entry) first_entry,
                                MAX(last_entry) last_entry
                             FROM scrub_activity
                             GROUP BY joobj,
                                      activity_type
                     )
    /* Compare SCRUBLIB objects against journal activity to find objects in Scrublib*/
    /* that have not been opened/closed/etc for prod purposes */
    /* Scrublib Inventory created from EndDr SQL Analysis script   */
                    SELECT x.ODOBNM,
                           x.ODOBTP,
                           x.ODOBAT,
                           x.ODCDAT,
                           x.ODUDAT
                        FROM HERAPERM.SCRUBLIB AS x
                        WHERE x.ODOBNM NOT IN (SELECT y.JOOBJ
                                      FROM scrub_activity_sum AS y
                                      WHERE activity_type NOT IN ('admin', 'system')
    /* Filters objects created in current year and less than filter month */
                                            AND y.JOOBJ IS NULL)
                              AND x.ODCRTS = 'ENDEAVOR'
                              /* Ignore objects created on EndDr/DPITest for Endeavor cleanup */
                              /* 12-2020 */
                              AND x.ODOBNM <> 'QDFTJRN' /* Ignore journal manager dtaara */
                              AND x.ODOBTP <> '*QMQRY'/* Ignore Query Objects *//* 12-2020 */
                              AND x.ODOBTP <> '*QRYDFN'/* Ignore Query Objects *//* 12-2020 */
                               (SELECT x.ODOBNM,
                                         x.ODOBTP,
                                         x.ODOBAT,
                                         x.ODCDAT,
                                         x.ODUDAT
                                      FROM HERAPERM.SCRUBLIB AS x
                                      WHERE x.ODOBNM NOT IN (SELECT Y.ODOBNM
                                                  FROM HERAPERM.SCRUBLIST AS y)))
            WITH DATA
;
```

Comment: Ok, so what DB is in use? ... and where is line 85? Probably best to add the entire message into the question.

Comment: AND x.ODOBTP <> '*QRYDFN'/* Ignore Query Objects *//* 12-2020 */ line 85

Comment: Formatting error encountered...   Line 85: "**" expected after this token   Failed to format 1 statements

Comment: Perhaps that comment should be: `/* 12-2020 */` instead of: `// 12-2020 */` ?

Comment: When i made the change the last lines turned green and all below it.

Comment: AND x.ODOBNM <> 'QDFTJRN' /* Ignore journal manager dtaara */
                              AND x.ODOBTP <> 'QMQRY'/* Ignore Query Objects /* 12-2020 */
                              AND x.ODOBTP <> *QRYDFN'/* Ignore Query Objects /* 12-2020 */
                              (SELECT x.ODOBNM,
                                         x.ODOBTP,

Comment: I missed a part of that, try: `/* Ignore Query Objects // 12-2020 */`

Comment: AND x.ODOBTP <> 'QRYDFN'/* Ignore Query Objects // 12-2020 */
                              (SELECT x.ODOBNM,
                                         x.ODOBTP,
                                         x.ODOBAT,
                                         x.ODCDAT,
                                         x.ODUDAT
                                      FROM HERAPERM.SCRUBLIB AS x
                                      WHERE x.ODOBNM NOT IN (SELECT Y.ODOBNM from Heraperm.scrublist as y)))

Comment: Same error Is it my select below that causing issue.

Comment: Oh, looks like a missing `AND` before that select, if that is the intent?

Comment: Formatting error encountered...   Line 92: "duration" inserted to complete scope   Line 92: "NOTNULL" inserted to complete scope   Line 86: "duration" inserted to complete scope   Line 86: "NOTNULL" inserted to complete scope   Failed to format 1 statements

Comment: What are those line references? ... I do not see `duration` nor `notnull` within the query.

Comment: I agree which is why I am even more confused.

Comment: FYI I did not write this only added the select to pull a few more that was missed.

Comment: Which is ok, but what is at lines 92 and 86 based on your editor's reference?

Comment: line 92                   WHERE x.ODOBNM NOT IN (SELECT Y.ODOBNM from Heraperm.scrublist as y)))

Comment: line 86    AND (SELECT x.ODOBNM,

Comment: Looks like a `,` is possibly needed after the `scrub_activity_sum` query?

Comment: So that worked then , correct

Comment: I had to go out of town.  There are two in the procedure but I don't see how you add comma to          scrub_activity_sum AS (

Comment: I rewrote it do you think this could work?